# Kotlin controller convert Any? to List data class

Tags: kotlin

I have a problem to create a controller at kotlin springboot, which is can accect Any? BodyRequest

i had try the solution that a found and using filterIsInstance for list, and as for single data but still not solve the problem yet

here is my code

```
fun create(@Valid @RequestBody dataRequest: Any?) : ResponseEntity<Response> {
    var lsCoa:List<Master> =  listOf();
    if (dataRequest is List<*>) {
        lsCoa = dataRequest.filterIsInstance<Master>()
        println(lsCoa.size) ==> this print 0
    }else if(dataRequest != null){
        println(2)  
        val b:Master = dataRequest as Master ==> this got error java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to asg.tax.model.Master
        if(b != null){
            lsCoa = listOf<Master>(b)
        }
    }
    return service.create(lsCoa)
}
```

this a master dataclass

```
data class Master (
    var code:String,
    var name:String? = "",
    var type:String? = ""
)
```

and this is the request example

Single Data

```
{
    "code":100005,
    "name":"Test",
    "type":"Total"
}
```

This is a multiple data

```
[
    {
        "code":100005,
        "name":"test 1",
        "type":"Total"
    },
    {
        "code":100006,
        "name":"test 2",
        "type":"Total"
    }
]
```

am i missing something??

I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Spring doesn't know which class it should parse the input into. It looks at your method signature, and tries to parse HTTP request into the method parameters.

If your method accepts `Any?`, Spring doesn't know to which class it should parse the input, so it just creates lists/maps and passes it to the method.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/ch15s03.html) for more info.